# Why changed history (by filter-branch) get reverted when using fetch

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I am using Github and trying to change the committer, author and email of old commits for a user, I used `.sh` file to change the history:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch -f --env-filter 'if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "<Old_Name>" ]; then
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=<New_Email>;
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="<New_Name>"
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL;
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME"; fi' -- --all
```

After executing the file I push all the changes with:

```
git push --all origin --force
```

For a moment of time it appears that it worked, but once I fetch, only the local branches stay as updated while the origin branches reset to old names

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Post the exact output of the push and the fetch commands.

Comment: @j6t I find a way by getting a local branch for all origin branches, thanks

Comment: By the way, the man page itself discourages the use of git-filter-branch. It recommends (e.g.) git-filter-repo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way by getting a local branch for all the branches before executing the update .sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
for branch in $(git branch --all | grep '^\s*remotes' | egrep --invert-match '(:?HEAD|master)$'); do
    git branch --track "${branch##*/}" "$branch"
done
```

please note this will create a local branch for all origin branches except master